# In WebStorm, if it is a function defined by ourselves, how to realize the prompt of this path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webstorm

[image]

[image]

Figure 1 shows that the path of can jump directly to the specified file. Figure 2 shows how to implement this operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [language injections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.2/using-language-injections.html) here: hit `Alt+Enter` within a string, choose **Inject language or reference > File Reference**

[image]

Comment: Do not see this option.

Comment: should be there if you put a cursor within a string literal and hit `Alt+Enter`